# how can I show my signal transaction data as project name

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know how can I show my database transaction data as auto amount, like as accounting system.

I need to show data in receivable amount, received amount, and due, like this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSFW8.jpg

```html
 <?php $sqlnew="SELECT tranjection.id, tranjection.date, project.project_name,project.amount,tranjection.receive_ammount FROM project JOIN tranjection on project.project_name=tranjection.project_name where project.project_name='dp' " ; $resultnew=mysql_query($sqlnew);
          $sl="1" ; ?>


          <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">


                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Sl</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Tran id</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Tran date</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Project Name</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Receivable Amount</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Receive Amount</strong>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"><strong>Due</strong>
                    </td>

                  </tr>







                  <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultnew)){ ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $sl++; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $rows[ 'id']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $rows[ 'date']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $rows[ 'project_name']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $rows[ 'amount']; ; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $rec1=$receive_ammount=$rows[ 'receive_ammount']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <?php echo $rec1 ; ?>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

                  <?php } ?>



                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: In what way does your actual output differ from what you want? I can't quite see where you are stuck.

Comment: here is database image>> http://www.mediafire.com/view/1jqo1cc3obx8k0j/h3.jpg

Comment: @SakilSuva I have given an answer, you should tell me about the status. working/not working/you'll try later/testing/found other solution etc. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should show that what are you getting as output/or if any error.

As per as I understand, last PHP code should be like following:

```
<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($resultnew)){
        if(!isset($rec1)) $rec1=$rows["amount"];
         //as we only want to set this in first loop. don't create $rec1 before while, if you created any then use another variable here. $rec1 should be unset. ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $sl++; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows[ 'id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows[ 'date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows[ 'project_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rec1; ?></td>
            <td><?php 
                  echo $receive_ammount=$rows[ 'receive_ammount'];
                  $rec1-=$receive_amount; ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $rec1 ; ?></td>
       </tr>
<?php } ?>
```